# Could glVertexAttribPointer() last at attribute value in OpenGL be a array ？

Tags: swift, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Now I have two custom shader, the position vertex shader and the color fragment shader. And I define two array data, position Array and color Array. This can make the gradient triangel in the iPhone. 
I didn't call the glBindBuffer() and glBufferData() for the VAO. but in the glVertexAttribPointer()，I send the position array to its last attribute and the color array too. Now, I feel confused，I found most documents explain the last attribute in this function, it is offset in vertex data array. now I send it to the array data and did not call the glBindBuffer() and glBufferData(), but it take effect。

```
lazy var postions : [GLfloat] = [
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    0.0,  0.5, 0.0,
    ]

lazy var colors : [GLfloat] = [
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1,
    ]
```

and this is the code about glVertexAttribPointer

```
let posistionAtt : GLuint = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position"))
    glVertexAttribPointer(posistionAtt, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(3 * MemoryLayout<GLfloat>.size), postions)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posistionAtt)

    let ptr = UnsafePointer<Int>.init(bitPattern: 3 * MemoryLayout<GLfloat>.size)
    let colorAtt : GLuint = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color"))
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorAtt, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(3 * MemoryLayout<GLfloat>.size), colors)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAtt)
```

[the result for the gradient triangel in the iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uJbM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no vertex buffer object is bound, then the last parameter is treated as a pointer to the data.

See [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification; 2.8. VERTEX ARRAYS; 21](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf):

> ```
> void VertexAttribPointer( uint index, int size, enum type, 
>                           boolean normalized,  sizei stride, 
>                           const void *pointer );
> ```
>
> ...
>   For each command, *pointer* specifies the location in memory of the first value of the first element of the array being specified.

See [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification; 2.9. BUFFER OBJECTS; 25](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf):

> ... When an array is sourced from
>   a buffer object, the *pointer* value of that array is used to compute an offset, in basic
>   machine units, into the data store of the buffer object. ...

This means, in case of

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
glVertexAttribPointer(...., pointer)
```

`pointer` has to be a pointer to the vertex array data - the array of vertex array data.

But in case of

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)  // vbo != 0
glVertexAttribPointer(...., offset)
```

`offset` has to be an offset, to the data store of `vbo`.

Comment: could i understand it like this. the positions and colors In this example,  their element without offset, so i can send the array as  glVertexAttribPointer(..., array)

Comment: @ADDICE Yes. For `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)` `glVertexAttribPointer(..., array)`,  `array` is the data array.